# asp.net with mvc; I am trying to pass a value from controller to the layout view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

so basically I want to pass a bool value from action in controller to layout view so I can show the login button acording to that bool value; Meaning bool IsLoggedin = false that means show login button
else that means IsLoggedin = true then don't show Login and instead show Sign out.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boHeP.png)

as you can see in the picture that it has detected in the index view that I am not logged in via the bool I mentioned.In my index acion:-

```
 if (Logged == false)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "You need to Login before you can add an item to cart");
            }
```

I have also implemented the same system to detect wheather the account logged in is an employee or not in my index view

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitPrice)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InStock)
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    @{ if (IsEmployee == true)
                        {
                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ProductID }, new { @class = "btn btn-sm btn-info" })
                            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ProductID }, new { @class = "btn btn-sm btn-primary" })
                            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ProductID }, new { @class = "btn btn-sm btn-danger" })
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "myForm" }))
                            {
                                <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="@item.ProductID" } />
                                <label for="Quant">Quantity</label> <input type="number" min="1" max="@item.InStock" value="0" name="Quant" class="MyInput" />
                                <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btn btn-sm myButton" } />
                            }
                        }
                    }
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

I want to do the same with Layout.cshtml

sorry for making it long; this is the first time i submitted a question before; I am new to ... life

Comment: I'm not sure if you are using identity in asp.net core to achieve login, If it is, you can just inject `SignInManager<T>` into your layout and use `SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)` to detect if user has logged in automatically .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are using identity in `Asp.Net Core` to achieve login, If it is, you can just inject `SignInManager<T>` into your layout and use `SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)` to automatically detect if user has logged in.

But if you want to pass a bool value from action in controller to layout, Session is more suitable for your situation, Please refer to this code:

Create a Partial View and inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into it:

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor ContextAccessor

<li class="nav-item">
                            
    @if (Convert.ToBoolean(ContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("Login")) == true)
    {
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a>
     }
     else
     {
         <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="LoggedIn">Log in</a>
     }
                                  
 </li>
```

Don't forget to register `HttpContextAccessor` in the `program.cs`

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Then refer this partial view in layout page

```
<partial name="_MyLogin"/>
```

In your login action, you need to:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("Login","true");
```

In your logout action, you need to:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("Login","false");
```

Now, after you access login method, The nav bar will not change until you access logout action.

Comment: thanks for the reply but this only changes list of the nav bar only in the log in view since that's where i put the ViewData["loggin"] = true;
`public ActionResult LoggedIn()
        {
            if (Session["CustomerID"] != null)
            {
                Session["Logged"] = true;
                ViewData["loggin"] = true;
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }
        }`
when I click home for example it refreshes the nav bar back to as if I hadn't logged in before

Comment: Hi @Noureldin Ahmed, I have updated my answer, It can help you solve this issue, If this answer can help you solve it, could you mark it as the answer? Thank you so much.